# How to use setDuration() method in SnackBar (Android Design Support Library)

Tags: android, android-design-library, snackbar

From Documentation: parameter duration - either be one of the predefined lengths: LENGTH_SHORT, LENGTH_LONG, **or a custom duration in milliseconds**.
But I can't set custom duration.

For example

```
Snackbar
    .make(parentLayout, "Feed cat?", 8000) // try here
    .setAction("Yes", snackOnClickListener)
    .setActionTextColor(Color.MAGENTA)
    .setDuration(8000) // try here
    .show();
```

but instead of 8 seconds Snackbar gone quickly.

Comment: What does "I can't set custom duration" mean? What are your specific symptoms?

Comment: @CommonsWare What he means is, he is not able to set a custom duration. It is only taking Length.Long and Length.Short. Output  "Must be one of: Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG" The documentations states that it is possible to set a custom duration in milliseconds.   I believe it is a mistake in the library and will probably be fixed. I tried many different methods but was not able to find the solution. If you can have a hack at it and find and answer please post it. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#setDuration(int)

Comment: @EugeneH: You're right; it's a bug. See my answer below.

Comment: I have this problem too. I use LENGTH_LONG but the problem do not solved and snackbar dismiss at third second...

Comment: Use this link.. http://www.technotalkative.com/part-2-welcome-snackbar-goodbye-toast/ It's complete demo by @pareshMayani GDG founder

Answer (score 66):

Based on the implementation of `Snackbar` and `SnackbarManager`, I can confirm Eugene H's assessment: it's a bug. From `SnackbarManager`:

```
private void scheduleTimeoutLocked(SnackbarRecord r) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(r);
    mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(mHandler, MSG_TIMEOUT, r),
            r.duration == Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                    ? LONG_DURATION_MS
                    : SHORT_DURATION_MS);
}
```

So, any value that is not `LENGTH_LONG` results in a short-duration snackbar.

I have filed [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175189) about it.

**Edit**: Has been fixed in revision 22.2.1. Check the release notes [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

The android docs have **NOT** been updated yet, but if you jump into the source code you'll notice that the parameter to the method setDuration(int duration) can either be one of LENGTH_SHORT, LENGTH_LONG, **LENGTH_INDEFINITE** or a custom duration in milliseconds

Comment: There are also issues with the FAB button on the support library. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175185#makechanges

Comment: @CommonsWare where did you find that source code? I'd love to know the values of `LONG_DURATION_MS` and `SHORT_DURATION_MS` for a temporary solution while we wait on the fix to be published, but the places that I have looked (AOSP, source in download manager) do not seem to have `Snackbar` nor `SnackbarManager` classes.

Comment: @ScottW: "where did you find that source code?" -- ...and I pulled the sword from the stone, and the Lady of the Lake then intoned "sorry, but the whole King of the Britons thing was a one-time deal; can I interest you in some MNC source code instead?". Or, possibly, I downloaded the source through the SDK Manager. Believe what you want. :-) "I'd love to know the values of LONG_DURATION_MS and SHORT_DURATION_MS" -- 1500 and 2750, respectively.

Comment: @ScottW: "the places that I have looked (AOSP, source in download manager) do not seem to have Snackbar nor SnackbarManager classes." -- on my machine, it is in `$ANDROID_SDK/sources/android-MNC/android/support/design/widget/SnackbarManager.java`.

Comment: @CommonsWare ah ha! Thank you! I was looking under `$ANDROID_SDK/extras/android/support/design/...`. I didn't even think to check in the M preview source.

Comment: Also, I choose to believe the Lady of the Lake story ;)

Comment: @ScottW: Glad you found it, and I am equally glad that you believe in Arthurian mythos! A quick note to anyone who stumbles upon this in the future, though -- I had the two numbers reversed in my comment. The long duration is 2750, and the short duration is 1500.

Comment: It looks like this issue has been fixed in M with Preview 2 but the fix has not yet been released in the Design Support Library.

Comment: This issue has been fixed in latest Design Support Library.  `dependencies  {  compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'  }`

Comment: In 22.2.1 it's possible to set a custom duration, but I had to disable the lint inspection for the setDuration method because it was giving an error (the inspection hasn't been updated correctly yet).

Comment: I like how Google ship the SDK. "Go figure out yourself  in our source code and report to us , you will do our QA. This way we will save money and time."

Answer (score 32):

Set the initial duration to LENGTH_INDEFINITE then set your custom duration afterwards:

```
Snackbar
.make(parentLayout, "Feed cat?", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
.setAction("Yes", snackOnClickListener)
.setActionTextColor(Color.MAGENTA)
.setDuration(8000)
.show();
```

**EDIT**

Setting a period directly in milliseconds now works;

```
Snackbar
.make(parentLayout, "Feed cat?", 8000)
.setAction("Yes", snackOnClickListener)
.setActionTextColor(Color.MAGENTA)
.show();
```

Comment: If we use 8000, Android compiles. But it doesn't compile, if we set a constant (DURATION = 8000). Write `@SuppressLint("WrongConstant")` for this situation.

Answer (score 9):

Since `'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'`

you can set the duration of your Snackbar to `LENGTH_INDEFINITE`it will make the Snackbar shown until it is dismissed or another snackbar is shown.

Answer (score 8):

This code working perfectly for me try this

```
Snackbar.make(view, "Hello SnackBar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        .setAction("Its Roy", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        })
        .setDuration(10000)
        .setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
        .show();
```

Comment: Worked on  Android M. Thank you

Comment: Works on Android Q too, this should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be fixed in

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Only Lint shows it red underlined, but it works.

Comment: Yes, for me as well. That's weird. I am using v23.1.1

Comment: add `//noinspection WrongConstant` to shut up Lint and it should work fine

Answer (score 5):

I have created a work around for this, i made a Class that sets snackbars with a custom duration using handler and postDelayed:

```
public class SnackBarMaker {

public static void snack(View content, String message, String actionText,  int actionTextColor, View.OnClickListener onClick){
    Snackbar.make(content, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            .setAction(actionText, onClick)
            .setActionTextColor(actionTextColor)
            .show();
}

public static void snackWithCustomTiming(View content, String message, int duration){
    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(content, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    snackbar.show();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            snackbar.dismiss();
        }
    },duration);
}
}
```

to use like this:

```
  //your duration
   int duration = 4000 
SnackBarMaker.snackWithCustomTiming(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)
                                               , getString(R.string.your_message), duration);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello there give this external library a try
 https://github.com/nispok/snackbar.
It is deprecated but it will easily solve your problem. It is moreover easy to implement. Before Support library i was using this library only for snackbars. Due to the duration problem of support library, i am happy to use this library only.

Answer (score 0):

In 2022 with AndroidX this solution is still actual: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44009407/7699617

Just set your **duration** in ms directly to `make` function:

```
Snackbar.make(context, messageId, DISMISS_TIMEOUT)
        .setAction(actionId, actionListener)
        .addCallback(dismissCallback)
        .show()

const val DISMISS_TIMEOUT = 6000
```

In addition, I made some calculations and find out **default duration values**:

- `Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG` ~ 3000ms
- `Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT` ~ 2000ms