# Arrange a BottomNavigationView, a FAB, and a FrameLayout in a CoordinatorLayout and make it work with Snackbar

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-coordinatorlayout, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android

I want to place a `FrameLayout` for hosting `Fragments`, a `BottomNavigationView` and a `FAB` inside a `CoordinatorLayout`. I would like to display a `Snackbar` over the `BottomNavigationView` and `FAB` to move up and down to accommodate the `Snackbar`. I have come up with the following layout but I am unable to get `Snackbar` and FAB behavior correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".landingpage.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_cont"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_main_activity_menu" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/extended_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/cont_desc"
    android:text="@string/chat"
    app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_chat_24" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

If I set LayoutParams like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32039244/3034693) then that margin 72dp margin is also displayed throwing FAB way up in the layout. If I don't use the margin the FAB will be stacked over the `BottomNavigationView`. I can use [addCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33076569/3034693) to set FAB margins programattically. Then also it will jump and then align itself to the right position. Overall it is not a good experience UX wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to display a `Snackbar` over the `BottomNavigationView`
> and FAB to move up and down to accommodate the `Snackbar`. I have come
> up with the following layout but I am unable to get `Snackbar` and FAB
> behavior correctly.

You get a bad behavior because you're trying to achieve something which is not common or maybe, ***not implemented this way*** by using `BottomNavigationView` and `FAB` together. It's actually more common to use `FAB` & `BottomAppBar` at the **bottom** of a layout.

---

> Then also it will jump and then align itself to the right position.
> Overall it is not a good experience UX wise.

Although it's not a good experience for users from a UX view, however, here are the approaches I may suggest:

**Best approach : Using another `CoordinatorLayout` inside `LinearLayout` (Supported the `FAB` animation):**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="Test" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_cont"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/SnackBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.ExtendedFloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/extended_fab"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:text="Chat"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                app:iconTint="@color/white" />

        </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"
            app:menu="@menu/escrow_menu" />
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And in Kotlin side:**

```
extended_fab.setOnClickListener {

            val snack: Snackbar = Snackbar.make(SnackBar, " Successfully ...!", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
            snack.show()
        }
```

---

**2. `BottomAppBar` & FAB & [`setAnchorView()`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Snackbar.md#anchoring-a-snackbar) method without `FAB` animation**

- Anchored to FAB

[image]

**Code:**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- your FrameLayout maybe -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
            android:text="SHOW SnakeBar"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/content_layout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />


    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="Test" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Personal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Personal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:visibility="invisible">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Personal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

            <TextView
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_baseline_send_24"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:text="Personal"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF">

            </TextView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---

**3. Using `FAB` - `BottomNavigationView` - `ConstraintLayout` without `FAB` animation**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floating_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/navigation"
        app:layout_insetEdge="bottom" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/escrow_menu" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="485dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: There is one problem though with the best approach. The NestedScrollView is under the LinearLayout which contains the BottomNavigationView. One has to use SnackBar layout but if you show snackbar from fragment then it would still show over bottomnavigationview. That is one of the biggest limitation of the answer.

Comment: Temp solution has been to call the activity method from the fragment and also to add a bottom margin of 56dp. I am not sure if there are better solutions.