# Xamarin.android how to add snackbar callback

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

How can I add a callback to a snackbar in c#? I found the way to do it but in java [How can I be notified when a Snackbar has dismissed itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33076569/10675707)

I tried to do the same in c#

```
 snackBar.AddCallback(new Snackbar.Callback
   { 
   
   });
```

I did find out that exists in snackbar callback class, but unfortunately I didn't find any info in xamarin docs about it.

```
      [Register("onDismissed", "(Landroid/support/design/widget/Snackbar;I)V", "GetOnDismissed_Landroid_support_design_widget_Snackbar_IHandler")]
      public virtual void OnDismissed(Snackbar transientBottomBar, int e);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define a `CallBack` first,then use `AddCallBack` method.

```
class MySnackCallBack : BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback
    {
        public override void OnDismissed(Java.Lang.Object transientBottomBar, int e)
        {
            base.OnDismissed(transientBottomBar, e);
          
        }

        public override void OnShown(Java.Lang.Object transientBottomBar)
        {
            base.OnShown(transientBottomBar);
            
        }
    }

Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.Make(view, message, Snackbar.LengthShort);
snackbar.AddCallback(new MySnackCallBack());
snackbar.Show();
```