# How to undo a deletion made using Room persistent library?

Tags: android, android-room

I am not sure if this is a qualified question .

I am using snackbar feature to undo a deletion and am really confused how to do it . I am using room library and after deletion ,the id associated with my data is also deleted so i cannot refer to the deleted id to insert the data at that specific id. When I click on undo button I want my data to be restored again to its old position and not as a new insertion.

Correct me if it is not at all possible or provide any alternatives. Thankyou

Comment: I quess you should perform deletion after snackbar disappears, in case user clicks undo - than you do nothing. This is how it's done in Gmail for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a snackbar action, how can I be sure it's safe to permanently delete a soft-deleted record from the database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056939/in-a-snackbar-action-how-can-i-be-sure-its-safe-to-permanently-delete-a-soft-d)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is by using Soft-Delete technique.

Add a new column and call it status for example flag with default value 0

Then if its deleted set the flag column to 1

and the query will only get results where flag = 0

and for un-deletion you can just set the flag from 1 to 0

Comment: I use “archived”, and filter the objects I get from the database by this field, if I need to delete, I set archived to true, otherwise archive is false, if I “delete” then all I do is set archived to true, that way you can keep the data and bring it back if necessary

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to follow yogourt's(Comment) suggestion. Because if you delete it from database and then again insert it then you have to fetch the entire list and update the recyclerView twice. So his suggested technique is better for performance. I will help you implement it. First of all I would suggest you maintain an `abstract BaseAdapter` class it's optional though as you can implement it directly in your `RecyclerAdapter`.

**BaseAdapter**

```
public abstract class BaseAdapter<T, VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder> extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VH> {
   private List<T> mList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    public T remove(int position) {
        if (position < getItemCount() && position>= 0) {
            T item = mList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
            return item;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void add(T item, int position) {
        mList.add(position, item);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    public void addAll(List<T> items) {
        mList.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void reload(List<T> items) {
        mList.clear();
        addAll(items);
    }
}
```

Now you should call the following `deleteItem()` method to delete temporarily from the recyclerView only and completely delete when it's timeout.

```
private void deleteItem(View view, final int position) {
        final YourEntity item = adapter.remove(position);
        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view, item.getName() + " is Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
        snackbar.setAction("Undo", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                adapter.add(item, position);
            }
        });
        snackbar.addCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onDismissed(Snackbar transientBottomBar, int event) {
                if (event == DISMISS_EVENT_TIMEOUT) {
                    // TODO delete from the database
                }
            }
        });
        snackbar.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the `Id` before you delete it to reference it later on in your code.