# Snackbar.setCallback() can not be resolved in Android AppCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have successfully added snackbar to my application, but when I try to add a callback compiler fails to resolve [setCallback()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar.html#setCallback%28android.support.design.widget.Snackbar.Callback%29) method. Is it a bug in AppCompat or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed in v23 of Android Design Support Library.

Comment: Does this mean I have to increase my targetSdk to 23 only to have a callback for snackbars?

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled at the same problem and it really looks like Snackbar docs mention a callback that does not exist.

There are ways to implement most common tasks, though. More info in these threads:

[How can I be notified when a Snackbar has dismissed itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30926380/how-can-i-be-notified-when-a-snackbar-has-dismissed-itself)

[Snackbar in Support Library doesn't include OnDismissListener()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639470/snackbar-in-support-library-doesnt-include-ondismisslistener)

Ugly hacks, but for us devs it's bread and butter ;)