# Android Snackbar duration

Tags: android, snackbar

I am trying to set the snack bar length using this:

```
Snackbar oSnackbar = Snackbar.make(Context, "Testing", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
oSnackbar.setDuration(8000);
oSnackbar.show();
```

But I get this compile error in setDuration:

> Must be one of Short, Long or Indefinite

In Android Studio gradle I use the dependency:

> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'

Any Help?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550792/how-to-use-setduration-method-in-snackbar-android-design-support-library

Comment: What I see there is that it was a bug that was solved with revision 22.2.1. But I am using 23.0.1 and still having the issue.

Comment: I tried your code, but i do not get the error.

Comment: Now i got it. I tried 22.2.0 and 23.0.1 versions. Using 22.2.0 no error, but if i change to 23.0.1, resync the project with gradle, then i got the same error too.

Comment: Oh wow. Did they make the same mistake twice?

Comment: According to this:http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#design , 23.1.0 is the latest version. With it, your code compiles fine, although setDuration's parameter is underlined.

Comment: Oh I see. It is underlined in red and if you put the mouse on it it displays the error BUT it works. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I updated to 23.1.1 and now it is not underlined in red.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the SDK version you are using to 23.0.1

Reference : http://androidgifts.com/android-material-design-snackbar/